# How to build a list of dicts from a SQLite3 database query in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite, generator, list-comprehension

In trying to produce a list of `dict`s from a SQLite3 query in Python 2.x, I can do something like:

```
import sqlite3
cur = sqlite3.connect('filename.db').cursor()
query = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM A_TABLE')
colname = [ d[0] for d in query.description ]
result_list = []
for r in query.fetchall():
  row = {}
  for i in range(len(colname)):
    row[colname[i]] = r[i]
  result_list.append(row)
  del row

cur.close()
cur.connection.close()
print result_list
```

With this, I try to get a list of dictionaries, with each key-value pair indicating the column name and the assigned value for the row.

But in spite of working and being reasonably understandable, the nested `for` cycles makes me think that there might be a Python idiom that simplifies this -- some clever use of comprehensions, specifically. I suspect that it might be possible to resort to generators, but I still don't quite understand how to use them. So I ask: is there a way to "compactify" the code and get the intended list of dictionaries by some use of comprehensions of generators and/or dicts?

Comment: The code in the question is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Just wanted to say thank you for posting it as it helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sqlite3
cur = sqlite3.connect('filename.db').cursor()
query = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM A_TABLE')
colname = [ d[0] for d in query.description ]
result_list = [ dict(zip(colname, r)) for r in query.fetchall() ]
cur.close()
cur.connection.close()
print result_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the inner for-loop with a dictionary comprehension like so:

```
row = dict((colname[i], r[i]) for i in range(len(colname)))
```

You can also replace the entire thing with a dictionary comprehension nested inside a list comprehension:

```
result_list = [dict((colname[i], r[i]) for i in range(len(colname)) for r in query.fetchall()]
```

I might actually recommend sticking with the outer for-loop however, as that seems more readable. Also, it seems to me that the `del row` is unnecessary. Can't you just rely on Python's garbage collector?

Answer (score 1):

@David K. Hess is right, except there is a typo. Line three should read:

```
query = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM A_TABLE')
```

I couldn't edit only three characters and don't have the reputation to comment.

Comment: Made the edit. In a case like this, if you comment on my answer, I'll be notified. Unfortunately, I don't get notified if another answer is added.